# eclipse jvm crash

Tags: eclipse

I meet a problem,When I start the eclipse,it always alert me:JVM terminated. Exit code=13

```
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx256m
```

I really don't know how to solve it,I ever installed eclipse in my linux system before,but I don't know why it begin to alert me this error after I change a new version eclipse,the eclipse before installed had been removed.Please help me solve it.Thanks.

Comment: Do I need install JVM or JDK again?

Answer (score 0):

Dear sir, you might have an incompatible version of Eclipse and JVM. Please, find the answer through this link below:

http://faisalbhagat.blogspot.com/2013/08/jvm-exit-code-13.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.